# Android preferences exception

Tags: android, exception, preferences

When I execute the following code:

```
Preferences.userRoot().nodeExists(strNodeName);
```

I get an exception :

```
java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Cannot get children names for User Preference Node: /!
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing user preferences, you'll want to use [android.content.SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). A good article describing how to use it [can be found here](http://www.old.kaloer.com/android-preferences/) and the ApiDemos sample app has a demo as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't because the code comes from a Java library and I can not change the code

Comment: Roman Nurik

Is this true?
If you look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref if says on the right that Preferences should be used for user prefs. I do kind of wonder why there are two different system?!?

Comment: @matt_lethargic, what is the other system you're referring to? `SharedPreferences` is the correct way of doing this on Android, for a number of reasons.